# How to access frame (not iframe) contents from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frame

I have 2 frames in one page like this (**home.html**)

```
<frameset rows="50%, 50%">
        <frame id="treeContent" src="treeContent.html" />
        <frame id="treeStatus"  src="treeStatus.html" />
</frameset>
```

and then in one frame (**treeStatus.html**) I have something like

```
<body style="margin: 0px">
<div id="statusText">Status bar for Tree</div>
</body>
```

I want from the top window to manipulate the div located in the child frame via jquery (e.g show and hide).

I have seen [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732915/accessing-iframe-content-using-jquery-on-ie) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444647/jquery-how-do-i-focus-on-contents-of-iframe-after-clearing) [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324764/accessing-a-frame-within-a-frame) [this](http://simple.procoding.net/2008/03/21/how-to-access-iframe-in-jquery/) and they suggest the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $('#treeStatus').contents().find("#statusText").hide();
     });
```

I do not know if this works with iframes but in my case where I have simple frames it does not seem to work. The code is placed inside home.html

Here is some output from firebug console

```
>>> $('#treeStatus')
[frame#treeStatus]
>>> $('#treeStatus').contents()
[]
>>> $('#treeStatus').children()
[]
```

So how do I access frame elements from the top frame? Am I missing something here?

**Answer**

After combining both answers here, the correct way is

```
$('#statusText',top.frames["treeStatus"].document).hide();
```

For this to work the frame must have the *name* attribute apart from the id, like this:

```
<frameset rows="50%, 50%">
            <frame id="treeContent" src="treeContent.html" />
            <frame name="treeStatus" id="treeStatus"  src="treeStatus.html" />
    </frameset>
```

Comment: Just a note: why using frames when you could use `position: fixed` to add a status bar (or log suggested by the size) always at the bottom of the viewport... supporting an ancient browser?

Comment: @alex this is just a minimal example I created for stackoverflow. The real application is completely different. It is more complicated than simple status bars. Frames are a requirement (Don't ask!).

Comment: OK, no worries. Just thought I'd add that (some people don't know about `position: fixed`).

Comment: Your answer is one I used as I was stuck on it.  You need to put your answer down too, rather than a comment.  HTH!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could grab the Frame and div you are wanting to manipulate and pass it into a variable.

```
var statusText = top.frames["treeStatus"].document.getElementById('statusText');
```

Then you can do anything you want to it through jQuery.

```
$(statusText).whatever();
```

Though sometimes you just can't get around having to use frames, keep in mind that the `<frame>` tag is obsoleted in HTML5. If you ever plan on moving up to HTML5, you'll have to use iFrames.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted because I believe that the whole purpose of jQuery is to avoid getElementById. However your answer helped me do what I want so I accept it.

Answer (score 5):

I have nested frames. In my case, to make it work i used command:

```
var statusText = 
top.document.getElementById("treeStatus").contentDocument.getElementById("statusText");
```

Then, as Charles already answered, you can do anything you want to it through jQuery:

```
$(statusText).whatever();
```

Comment: contentDocument is what I was looking for! I too have nested frames, thanks for this post!

Answer (score 3):

https://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2009/07/30/cross-frame-access-with-jquery/

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#Button1").click(function(){
      $(parent.rightFrame.document).contents().find(‘#TextBox1’).val(‘Hello from left frame!’);
     });
    });
```

But I used :

```
    $.post("content_right.php",{id:id},function(data)
     $(parent.frames["content_right"].document.body).html(data) ;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

For a pure jquery solution (that doesn't require `top.frames` etc), the following seems to work:

```
$('some selector for item from frame' ,$('frame selector')[0].contentDocument)
```

This has the advantage that it works for nested frames:

```
$('inner frame item selector', $('inner frame selector', $('outer frame selector')[0].contentDocument)[0].contentDocument)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following successfully:

```
$(  '#foo',  top.frames['bar'].document  )
```

(also works with nested frames that are automagically appended in `top.frames`)