# How can i access the frame that my page is in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frame

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access frame (not iframe) contents from jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921957/how-to-access-frame-not-iframe-contents-from-jquery)

So, I'm trying to use some jquery in my project, and I'm having difficult with the jQuery parts.

What I'm trying to do is, I have three frames on the intranet system, the Top, that have some links, the left frame, who have the menu, and the main frame, that have the pages and everything else. When the person clicks on a Menu, and start navigating through the pages, i want to give an option to the person hides the left frames, so the page would get bigger, what is better for visualization.

But the left frame loads a page that loads the menu, and I can't hide the frame, cause the button that would hide the frame it's on the page that are Loaded by the page which had the frame.

I know it's confusing but i can't explain this much better in english.

So, Can i access the frame and hide it, with a button that are on the page loaded in the frame?

I'm trying to do this

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        $(document).ready(function(){   
             $("#btnTeste").click(function(){
                $("#menuFrame").hide();  
             }); 
        });
</script>
```

but with no sucess, because the frame it's not on the page. Trying to put parent on the second parameter doesn't help anyways.

Hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: don't use frames for layouts.