# Passing a variable between two different JSPs

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, web-applications

I am new to web application development, i have 2 different frames on a HTML page. One is having graphs.jsp and other is having location.jsp. There is a slider in Location.jsp that gives some value that i want to pass to graphs.jsp.

here is the code on Location.jsp

```
  <script>

  var Myvariable=0;


$( function() 

{
$( "#slider1" ).slider({
  value:100,
  min: 0,
  max: 500,
  step: 10,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
      Myvariable=ui.value;
    $( "#amount" ).val(  "$"+Myvariable);

        }


 });
 $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider1" ).slider( "value" ) );


} );


</script>
```

and here is my Graph.jsp

```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        var FetchedValueFromLocation.jsp= xxxx;
        var j = 1305;
        var k = 1512;
        var l = j * k + i;




         <%-- For piechart (GOOGLE graphs) --%>


        google.charts.load("current", {packages: ["corechart"]});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {


            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
                ['Lighting', FetchedValueFromLocation.jsp],
                ['HVAC', j],
                ['Misc', k]
            ]);


            var options = {
                title: 'END USE',
                width: 400,
                height: 300,
                pieHole: 0.4
            };


            var chart3 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
            chart3.draw(data, options);
            chart3.setPlotArea(30, 20, 200, 200);
        }

    </script>
```

Now i want to fetch the slider value in the Location.jsp and update the value of pie chart in the Graphs.jsp in realtime. i have used google graphs library, is it okay to use this or how can i make this work. Please help. thanks!

Comment: I don't see any JSP code so it could by any html file and thus the java and jsp tags might not fit. I further guess you don't want to send the data to the server first so you'd need to communicate between frames. I'm no html expert but AFAIK communication between frames isn't that easy and frames aren't use that often anyways. Can you put both elements on the same page?

Comment: Actually No, there are a lot of JSP frames having user input that need to be connected to the graphs.jsp to respond. how can i pass a simple integer value from Location.jsp to graphs.jsp?

Comment: As I mentioned you don't work on jsps but on the resulting html pages (since you seem to want to do it on the client side and jsps are a server side technology). Thus you're looking for how to access one frame from another via JavaScript. A quick search resulted in pages like this, which should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921957/how-to-access-frame-not-iframe-contents-from-jquery